# Should the FAQ have a restriction on time-dependent Questions?

Tags: discussion, faq-for-site

For example, the [UnityAnswers FAQ](http://answers.unity3d.com/faq):

> Don't write things that will be
>   irrelevant in a few days.

This is in response to [Doom 3 Codebase release details?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/doom-3-codebase-release-details)

I was going to comment it with a link from our GameDev FAQ, until I *looked* at the FAQ, and realized it doesn't say anything about time restrictions. Now, it's possible the *Doom* Question won't become irrelevant, as it would at least have a link to the actual *code*.

But in general, is it a good idea to avoid time-dependent Questions, and/or should the FAQ be updated?

Comment: And why exactly is *faq* a reserved tag, anyway?

Comment: Because it makes a kind of faq page, you have to look at Meta.SO to really get it though. If you look at the side you will see frequently asked http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, we already have a close case for that. Too Localized, can also refer to being only relevant to a particular point in time.

Comment: But how would people know the question should be closed (or not asked at all)? I'm wondering if we should *modify* the FAQ (or have the moderators do it).

Comment: Just checked, the FAQ page is kind of lacking on close reasons. If you want you can add it in the "What should our FAQ" contain question for voting, if not I'll add it when I get freetime later tonight.

Comment: +1 For the sake of Community♦, and the issue doesn't seem to be much of a general problem.